# how to assign the result of a batch command to a variable

Tags: batch-file

If on the command line I execute:

```
c:\digitemp.exe -t0 -o%C -q  > res1.txt
```

`res1.txt` contains correctly the numerical temperature in Celsius (say: 24.23456). But if the same command is executed inside a bat file (say: test.bat):

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Hola pootol!
ECHO.
c:\digitemp.exe -t0 -o%C -q  > res1.txt 
rem set pootol = < res1.txt
rem set pootol
ECHO Prem una tecla per sortir.
pause > null
```

`res1.txt` contains a wrong Celsius value that I suspect is related to the argument `" -o%C "`. As you can see I `rem` the variable assing cause pootol var is wrong assigned with the Celsius value before it is mentioned. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have tried to fix some grammar and formatting mistakes in your question. However, I have not idea what "As you can see I `rem` the variable assing cause pootol var is wrong assigned with the Celsius value before it is mentioned" means. Can you try clarifying this yourself?

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your case is the `%` sign, as it's evaluated different in the cmd-line and in batch files.
In batch files you can escape it with doubling it.

So your code looks like

```
c:\digitemp.exe -t0 -o%%C -q  > res1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In batch files `%` is used to denote variables.  So `%C` is interpreted inside the batch file as a variable and replaced with its value.  Since it doesn't have a value it is replaced with an empty string.

Use the caret `^` character to escape the `%` so that the interpreter treats the `%` as a normal character.

```
c:\digitemp.exe -t0 -o^%C -q  > res1.txt
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but i get the same result with the caret ^ escape char as you said. There is another scape character to try? Thanks again!

Comment: found it! thanks -o%%C (http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php) it works now!